# Asymptotics for a peculiar kind of squarefree numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Let  $ n $ denote a square free positive composite integer,  $ \omega(n) $ its number of prime factors,  $ P_{i}(n) $ its  $ i $ -th prime factor.

Can we determine an asymptotics for the  number of  $ n $ below  $ x $  such that  $ P_{\omega(n)}-P_{1}(n)<\left(\dfrac{n}{\omega(n)}\right)^{1/\omega(n)} $?

Comment: $i$th biggest prime factor, or $i$th smallest prime factor?

Comment: $ i $-th prime factor in increasing order. For example, if  $ n=42=2.3.7 $,  $ P_{1}(n)=2 $ ,  $ P_{2}(n)=3 $ ,  $ P_{3}(n)=7 $ .

Comment: You can divide out by the fractional power of n (which I call w) to get (b-c) is less than 1, which means the largest prime factor P is always less than twice the geometric mean of the factors (w). If P is near 2w, then the number of factors must be immensely large, and all near and most less than w.  If P is near w, again most of the other factors must also be near w, and there can't be many far away from w. It almost becomes a counting problem, where I would be surprised if the number of solutions was greater than w. Gerhard "The A And The W" Paseman, 2017.05.22.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please ignore the previous version of this answer.

Motivated by Lucia's comment, we use smooth numbers to show that the number in question is $o(x)$. First note that for $100\%$ of all integers one has 
$P_1(n)\leq \log \log \log n$, as a typical application of the naive Eratosthenes' sieve. Also by Hardy-Ramanujan one has for $100\%$ of all integers $n\leq x$ that $$ n^{1/\omega(n)}\leq x^{2/\log \log x}.$$ Therefore $$ p|n,n\leq x\Rightarrow p\leq x^{2/\log \log x}+\log \log \log x \leq x^{3/\log \log x}.$$ Now by estimates $(1,7),(1.8)$ here http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/msrire.pdf
one has that for every $A>0$ the number of integers $n\leq x$ in the question is at most $$\ll x \left(\frac{3\mathrm{e}}{(\log \log x)(\log \log \log x)}\right)^{(\log \log x)/3}\ll_A \frac{x}{(\log x)^A}.$$

Comment: This seems wrong.  It is $\log \log P_i(n)$ that is close to $i$ often.   Indeed even the $i$-th prime itself is around $i\log i$.   In fact, the number of integers satisfying the relation in the question is $o(x)$.

Comment: Yes indeed, sorry, i will try to fix that.